# How to retreive objects ambiguous lookup field with SOQL?

Tags: soql

I want to query `VoiceCall`s with their relevant records. The `VoiceCall` object has a field called `RelatedRecordId`, which is of type `Lookup(Account,Contact,Lead,Case,Opportunity)`. How do I know which object this record is related to? Do I need to have a blanket `SELECT` for all objects that this field could be related to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have here is a *polymorphic relationship field*.

There is documentation on [Working with polymorphic relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm)

In a normal query that pulls in data from a parent record, you use the relationship field name and dot notation
`[SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Opportunity]`

The main difference when working with polymorphic relationships is that we use something close to a switch statement

```sql
[SELECT TYPEOF RelatedRecord
    WHEN Account
      THEN Name, Phone, My_Custom_Field__c
    WHEN Contact
      THEN Name, Phone, Email, CreatedDate
    WHEN Opportunity
      THEN Name, StageName, Amount
    END
FROM VoiceCall
WHERE Id IN :callsList
]
```

Then when you iterate over the results, you need to check what SObject the polymorphic relationship field points to before it's safe to use the result

```java
for(VoiceCall vCall :<query here>){
    if(vCall.RelatedRecord instanceOf Account){
        // It's now safe to use dot-notation to access the account fields
        //   that you queried
        Account acct = vCall.RelatedRecord;
        system.debug(acct.Phone);
    }
}
```

If you filter your query so that it only returns records that are related to a single type, then you don't need to bother with checking  `instanceOf`.

```java
// Still need to use TYPEOF - WHEN - THEN - END so that Salesforce
//   can perform compile-time checks
for(VoiceCall vCall :[SELECT Id TYPEOF What WHEN Opportunity THEN StageName END FROM VoiceCall WHERE What.Type = 'Opportunity'){
    // You still need to put the related record into a concrete SObject
    //   type to be able to use dot-notation on most fields
    Opportunity opp = vCall.RelatedRecord;
    system.debug(opp.StageName);

    // Alternatively, using SObject's .get() method is viable
    system.debug(vCall.RelatedRecord.get('StageName'));

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Two follow-ups:
1. Is it possible to pull `TYPEOF RelatedRecord` as a separate field? (I will process data in javascript so I won't have access to `instanceOf Account`)
2. Is it possible to add common fields after `END`?

Comment: @BuğraGündüz You can add common fields either before `TYPEOF`, or after `END`. The `TYPEOF` in the query is a keyword, so you wouldn't be able to write `console.log(mySFRecord.typeof);` in Javascript. Given that data would be serialized as JSON to pass it to Javascript, you would likely be able to figure out the related record type in Javascript by looking at `mySFRecord.What.attributes.type` (and then accessing related fields as normal, `mySFRecord.What.Phone`)